# Asking user for info in loop: how to keep working as many times as the user wants?

Tags: c++, loops

Well I'm making an program about payrolls and I'm stuck. In the program, after the user has entered the number of employees, I have to make an loop, allowing the user to enter information for each of the employees. Then the data entered is to be stored in my employees array, which I made. Ive attempted my problem with the `while(numberOfEmployees < MAXSIZE)` part of my program. Is that right?

This is what I have now:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAXSIZE = 20;

struct EmployeeT
{
    char name[MAXSIZE];
    char title;
    double gross;
    double tax;
    double net;
};

EmployeeT employees[MAXSIZE];

int main()
{
    cout << "How many Employees? ";
    int numberOfEmployees;
    cin >> numberOfEmployees;

    while(numberOfEmployees > MAXSIZE)
    {
        cout << "Error: Maximum number of employees is 20\n";
        cout << "How many Employees? ";
        cin >> numberOfEmployees;
    }

    int name;
    int title;
    double gross;
    double tax;
    double net;

    for (int count=0; count<numberOfEmployees; count++)
    {
        cout << "Name: \n";
        cin >> employees[ count ].name;

        cout << "Title: \n";
        cin >> employees[ count ].title;

        cout << "Gross: \n";
        cin >> employees[ count ].gross;

        cout << "Tax: \n";
        cin >> employees[ count ].tax;

        cout << "Net: ";
        cin >> employees[ count ].net;
    }
}
```

I just updated it to this. My last question is how do I get the second loop to keep working as many times as the user wants. For as many employees the user types in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

1- Place a i++ somewhere inside the while loop
(Why not use a for loop?)

2- name and title should probably be a string:

```
#include <string>
//in the main:
std:string name;
```

3- the while condition should be:

```
while(i<numberOfEmployees && i<MAXSIZE)
```

(Edit: I see you just corrected that one)

Edit: I just noticed you always write to the same variables. Write to employees[i].name etc. instead.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Some typos and missing newlines... sorry

Comment: Are you talking about me using numberOfEmployees too much?

Comment: Oh sorry haha. I changed my program. Look at it now. Thanks again

Comment: That looks more like it ;-) Don't forget to mark the answer that solved it with the green checkmark

Comment: My last question is how do I get the second loop to keep working as many times as the user wants. For as many employees the user types in?

Comment: You could check for an 'x' or something to interrupt the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < numberOfEmployees && i < MAXSIZE) {
    // some action here
    i++;
}
```

or:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEmployees && i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
    //some action here
}
```

Also you can just choose a minimum number of `numberOfEmployees` and `MAXSIZE` to build a condition with:

```
numberOfEmployees = numberOfEmployees <= MAXSIZE ? numberOfEmployees : MAXSIZE;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEmployees; i++) { ... }
```

**UPD:** as for for the first loop you can change the condition to `numberOfEmployees > MAXSIZE` and remove inner `if` clause

Comment: I actually have another while loop before this one. When I try to run the program, the first while loop works, but then the program quits without the second while loop working.

Comment: Yea that worked. Now, both loops work, but during the second loop, after it asked for the name and I type a name in, the program quits.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop, when you check if the user enters a too large value, it never ends! Instead of doing `while (true)`, just use `while (numberOfEmployees > MAXSIZE)` and skip the `if` (but not the content inside the `if`).

Also, since you already make sure`numberOfEmployees` is valid, you don't need the `&& i < MAXSIZE` condition in your second loop.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get the second loop to keep working as many times as the
>   user wants. For as many employees the user types in?

```
for (int count=0; count<numberOfEmployees; count++)
{
    cout << "Name: \n";
    cin >> employees[ count ].name;

    cout << "Title: \n";
    cin >> employees[ count ].title;

    cout << "Gross: \n";
    cin >> employees[ count ].gross;

    cout << "Tax: \n";
    cin >> employees[ count ].tax;

    cout << "Net: ";
    cin >> employees[ count ].net;
    //Ask user if he wants to add more employees, if no break the loop else iterate again
     cout<<"Do u want to continue: 1 to continue 0 to exit");
     cin>>flag;
     if(flag==0)
          break;
}
```

}